# add execute permission to role in MS SQl

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a website that is connecting to the DB with the credentials for user `XX`. User `XX` is part of role `YY`.

I need to grant all users in role `YY` permission to `Execute` certain Stored Procedures.

I understand how to grand access to users but how to do the same for ROLES?

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [storedProcName] TO [userName]
```

Comment: The T-SQL syntax to grant execute permissions to roles is the same.

Answer (score 0):

By using SSMS :

Expand Databases, expand the database in which the procedure belongs, and then expand Programmability. Expand Stored Procedures, right-click the procedure to grant permissions on, and then click Properties. From Stored Procedure Properties, select the Permissions page.In Select Users or Roles, click Object Types to add or clear the users and roles you want or Click Browse to display the list of users or roles. Select the users or roles to whom permissions should be granted.

By Query TSQL :

USE DBnamw;
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::schema.uspxxz
    TO role;
GO